# gsutil not working in GCE

Tags: boto, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gsutil

So when I bring up a GCE instance using the standard debian 7 image, and issue a "gsutil config" command, it fails with the following message:

`jcortez@master:~$ gsutil config
Failure: No handler was ready to authenticate. 4 handlers were checked. ['ComputeAuth', 'OAuth2Auth', 'OAuth2ServiceAccountAuth', 'HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials.`

I've tried it on the debian 6 and centos instances and had the same results.  Issuing "gcutil config" works fine however.  I gather I need to set up my ~/.boto file but I'm not sure what to.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using service account scopes as [E. Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17621433/92445) mentions is the recommended way to use gsutil on Compute Engine, so the images are configured to get OAuth access tokens from the metadata server in /etc/boto.cfg:

```
[GoogleCompute]
service_account = default
```

If you want to manage gsutil config yourself, rename /etc/boto.cfg, and `gsutil config` should work:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/boto.cfg /etc/boto.cfg.orig
$ gsutil config
This script will create a boto config file at
/home/<...snipped...>/.boto
containing your credentials, based on your responses to the following questions.
<...snip...>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. That /etc/boto.cfg rename worked. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to [use a service account](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#using) to have access to Cloud Storage without needing to enter credentials?

It sounds like gsutil is searching for an OAuth access token with the appropriate scopes and is not finding one.  You can ensure that your VM has access to Google Cloud Storage by requesting the `storage-rw` or `storage-full` permission when starting your VM via `gcutil`, or by selecting the appropriate privileges under "Project Access" on the UI console.  For `gcutil`, something like the following should work:

```
> gcutil addinstance worker-1 \  
> --service_account_scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly
```

Comment: I just ran a basic "gcutil addinstance <name>" command to start the instance. I'd like to avoid the service account option if possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you configured your GCE instance, did you set it up with a service account configured? Older versions of gsutil got confused when you attempted to run gsutil config when you already had service account credentials configured.

If you already have a service account configured you shouldn't need to run gsutil config - you should be able to simply run gsutil ls, cp, etc. (it will use credentials located elsewhere than your ~/.boto file).

If you really do want to run gsutil config (e.g., to set up credentials associated with your login identity, rather than service account credentials), you could try downloading the current gsutil from http://storage.googleapis.com/pub/gsutil.tar.gz, unpacking it, and running that copy of gsutil. Note that if you do this, the personal credentials you create by running gsutil config will essentially "hide" your service account credentials (i.e., you would need to move your .boto file aside if you ever want to user your service account credentials again).

Mike Schwartz, Google Cloud Storage team

Comment: No, I didn't create the instance with a service account configured. I may end up needing to do that but wanted to avoid it for now. I did run it with the latest gcutil (3.31) and had the same results. Any gcutil command I run has the same failure message. The only thing that runs is "gcutil --help".

Comment: Btw, the command I used to create the instance was just a basic "gcutil addinstance <name>". And when it comes up, I ssh in and type "gsutil config" (or any gsutil command) and I will get this failure.

Answer (score 1):

FYI I'm working on some changes to gsutil now that will handle the problem you encountered more smoothly. That version should be out within the next week or two.

Mike