# Configuring gsutil with service account credentials from a script

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm looking to configure gsutil with a service account from an unattended init script running on a vanilla ubuntu 14 EC2 instance. I've tried several methods for interacting with gsutil unattendedly without success as yet.
Would appreciate your advice as to how this can be approached.

This is a bash script i tried running:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

gsutil config -e <<'EOF'
XXX.gserviceaccount.com
/XXX/service_account_private_key.p12
PASSWORD
N
APP_NAME
EOF
```

I Also tried running a command in the following structure, still without success:

```
{ echo "XXX.gserviceaccount.com"; echo "/XXX/service_account_private_key.p12"; echo "PASSWORD"; echo "N"; echo "APP_NAME"; } | gsutil config -e
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Need you paste error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to edit the `~/.boto` or `/etc/boto.cfg` with the required credential information.

- See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config
- And: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17623996/2026508

Comment: Exactly. There's no need to run `gsutil config` at all. You can just copy the boto config and p12 file to the destination machine.

Comment: That did it, i created a boto file with tokens for replacing with actual configuration data and it works. Thanks a lot for your help!